# sorting dictionary values in python - descending alphabetically

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary:-

```
higharr = {'Alex':2,
           'Steve':3,
           'Andy':4,
           'Wallace':6,
           'Andy':3,
           'Andy':5,
           'Dan':1,
           'Dan':0,
           'Steve':3,
           'Steve':8}

for score in sorted(higharr.values(), reverse=True):
    print (score)
```

I would like to print out the keys with the values with the values being in descending alphabetical order. The descending part is working but I am unsure about how to add the corresponding key to the left of it.

Thank you

Comment: have a look at see what higharr.keys() does. Then sort that list perhaps and ask the dict for those keys in that order?.....

Comment: You can't have this dictionary - your keys aren't unique.  Try printing higharr.  You are likely to find you're missing entries.

Comment: You say "descending alphabetical order" but you are currently sorting by the numerical values.  What order do you want?

Comment: its not clear what you want , can you add your expected out put ?

Comment: A complete new SO-user, so please be civil, polite and do not vote him immediately down. That are just bad manners.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am new to all this. I seem to have cracked it now. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there may be a bit of confusion as to what entries in your dictionary are "keys" and which are "values".  In Python, a dictionary is formed with key-value pairs by {key:value}.  Thus, in higharr, the keys are the names, and the values are the integers to 
the right of the names.

As others have mentioned, higharr may not function exactly as you expect, since the keys (the names) of the dictionary are not unique:

```
>>> higharr = {'Alex':2,
               'Steve':3,
               'Andy':4,
               'Wallace':6,
               'Andy':3,
               'Andy':5,
               'Dan':1,
               'Dan':0,
               'Steve':3,
               'Steve':8}

>>> higharr
{'Steve': 8, 'Alex': 2, 'Wallace': 6, 'Andy': 5, 'Dan': 0}
```

As you can see, the later key-value pairs you add will overwrite the earlier ones.
That being said, you can sort and print the pairs in a dictionary will all unique keys as you ask with the following:

```
>>> for entry in sorted(higharr.items(), key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
...     print(entry)
...
('Steve', 8)
('Wallace', 6)
('Andy', 5)
('Alex', 2)
('Dan', 0)
```

If instead you wanted to sort the keys by descending alphabetical order, you can do basically the same thing:

```
>>> for entry in sorted(higharr.items(), key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True):
...     print(entry)
... 
('Wallace', 6)
('Steve', 8)
('Dan', 0)
('Andy', 5)
('Alex', 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use another data-structure, because you have duplicate keys.
But in general you might consider this:

```
from operator import itemgetter
for i in sorted(higharr.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking?

```
for key, score in sorted(higharr.values(), reverse=True):
    print (key, score)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close. Enumerate the dictionary's items and use a custom sort key:

```
>>> for name, score in sorted(higharr.iteritems(), key=lambda item:item[1], reverse=True):
...     print name, score
...
Steve 8
Wallace 6
Andy 5
Alex 2
Dan 0
>>>
```